# Scale down UIView and it's subview simultaneously in swift 5?

Tags: ios, uiview, scale, swift5

I have created `UIView` and it has one subview and it's containing shape object which are creating using `UIBezierPath`, and `UIView` has fixed height and width (**image 1**). When i click the blue color button, it should be scale down to another fixed width and height. I have applied  `CGAffineTransform` to subview and, i guess it is scale down properly, but since `topAnchor` and `leftAchor` has constant values, after scale down it is not displaying properly (**image 2**).I will attach my source code here and screenshots, please, analyze this and can someone suggest better approach for how to do this ? and highly appreciate ur feedback and comments.

code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var screenView: UIView!
    var button: UIButton!
    
    let widthOfScaleDownView: CGFloat = 200
    let heightOfScaleDownView: CGFloat = 300
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        screenView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        screenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        screenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(screenView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            screenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 800),
            screenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 600),
            screenView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
            screenView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
        button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 950),
            button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 350)
        ])
        button.setTitle("click", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scaleDownView(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        let shapeView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        shapeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
        let shape = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 50)
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = shape.cgPath
        layer.lineWidth = 2
        shapeView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        
        screenView.addSubview(shapeView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            shapeView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: screenView.topAnchor, constant: 250),
            shapeView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: screenView.leftAnchor, constant: 150)
        ])
    }
    
    @IBAction func scaleDownView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let widthScale = widthOfScaleDownView/screenView.frame.width
        let heightScale = heightOfScaleDownView/screenView.frame.height
        screenView.subviews.forEach{ view in
            view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: widthScale, y: heightScale)
        }
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            screenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightOfScaleDownView),
            screenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: widthOfScaleDownView),
            screenView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
            screenView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
        
    }
    
    
}
```

[image: before to scale]

[image: after scale]

Comment: Do you really want to use `CGAffineTransform`? Or, do you want to change the size of the view by changing its constraints?

Comment: @DonMag actually, i need to change the size of the red color view and black color box subview. so resize factor should be effected to every where of the view ex: red color view, black color view, gap difference between red color and black color edges. Actually result should be similar to image 1 zoom out :) , `CGAffineTransform` not mandatory, let me know if you have good approach thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple things...

1 - When you use `CGAffineTransform` to change a view, it will automatically affect the view's subviews. So no need for a loop.

2 - Transforms are cumulative, so when "going back" to the original scale, use `.identity` instead of another scale transform.

3 - You cannot set a constraint multiple times. So if you do:

```
screenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 800)
```

and then you ***also*** do:

```
screenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: heightOfScaleDownView)
```

you will get auto-layout conflicts... the view cannot be both 800-pts tall **and**
300-pts tall at the same time.

Take a look at the changes I made to your code. I also added a 1-second animation to the scale transform so you can see what it's doing:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    var screenView: UIView!
    var button: UIButton!
    
    let widthOfScaleDownView: CGFloat = 200
    let heightOfScaleDownView: CGFloat = 300
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        
        screenView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        screenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        screenView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(screenView)
        
        // constrain screenView
        //  width: 800 height: 600
        //  centered X and Y
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            screenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 800),
            screenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 600),
            screenView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor, constant: 0),
            screenView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])

        button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        self.view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 950),
            button.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leftAnchor, constant: 350)
        ])
        button.setTitle("click", for: .normal)
        button.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scaleDownView(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        let shapeView = UIView(frame: .zero)
        shapeView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300)
        let shape = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, cornerRadius: 50)
        let layer = CAShapeLayer()
        layer.path = shape.cgPath
        layer.lineWidth = 2
        shapeView.layer.addSublayer(layer)
        
        screenView.addSubview(shapeView)
        
        // constrain shapeView
        //  width: 300 height: 300
        //  centered X and Y in screenView
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            shapeView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            shapeView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            shapeView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: screenView.centerXAnchor),
            shapeView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: screenView.centerYAnchor),
        ])
    }
    
    @IBAction func scaleDownView(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let widthScale = widthOfScaleDownView/screenView.frame.width
        let heightScale = heightOfScaleDownView/screenView.frame.height

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0) {
            // if we have already been scaled down
            if widthScale == 1 {
                // animate the scale transform back to original (don't add another transform)
                self.screenView.transform = .identity
            } else {
                // animate the scale-down transform
                self.screenView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: widthScale, y: heightScale)
            }
        }

        // do NOT change screenView constraints!
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Yes, Thanks lot for all your advice, i followed your 3 points and I was able to resolve my issue successfully, thanks lot for help